# Crouton equivalence on iOS?

Tags: ios, crouton

I'm just restarting out with iOS trying to port an Android app. What would be the most equivalent example of an android crouton on iOS? I couldn't find any third party libraries except one abandoned project: https://github.com/kvandermast/crouton-ios .

Basically, if one wants to show a quick context relevant message that doesn't require user action to dismiss, what would s/he use?

Comment: what makes you think it is abandoned?

Comment: @vikingosegundo 7 commits, the last of which was 8 months ago.

Comment: As for those who think it's off topic, I'm asking for the iOS equivalent of a crouton. As far as I know, croutons aren't a thing in iOS (nor have I seen much in action).

Comment: This Question is marked off-topic due to it's opinion based nature. Although I was looking for something like this and it helped me. So a +1 for ya.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of question I was looking for. It's a shame libraries are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually a few libraries out there.
For example [CRToast](https://github.com/cruffenach/CRToast/blob/master/README.md) or [JDStatusBarNotification](https://github.com/jaydee3/JDStatusBarNotification/blob/master/README.md).

I recommend using [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) to find third party libraries.

I hope this will help you!